# Subir uno o varios archivos a servidor recibidos en un json

Tags: php, json

Recibo un json de datos, que puede contener uno o varios adjuntos, todos ellos se recibe el fichero en base64. Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
{
"id": 1,
"data": {
    "nombre": "Nombre",
    "file1": "Mhuc2dvCg==",
    "file2": "Yhj4dysYn==",
    "file3": "Jusj6Hism==",
    "file4": "Rhsy7Yhah==",
    ...
    }
}
```

He conseguido que suba un archivo, pero no sé cómo hacer que identifique a cada uno de los que llegan en el json.
Es decir, si hago:

```
$adjunto1 = isset($input['data']['file1']) ? $input['data']['file1'] : '';
```

Y tras esto llamo a la función `subirFichero($adjunto1);` todo funciona correctamente. Pero ¿cómo hago para reconocer en el json todos los ficheros que llegan, es decir, que compruebe que si comienza por "file" es un fichero adjunto y los vaya insertando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos soluciones dependiendo de si puedes/quieres mejorar o no la estructura de los datos JSON enviados:

### Manteniendo el formato JSON

Puedes iterar por cada elemento mediante un `foreach` y comprobar que el índice no sea `nombre`:

```
<?php
/* Reproducimos la variable $input: */
$input = json_decode('
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
        "nombre": "Nombre",
        "file1": "Mhuc2dvCg==",
        "file2": "Yhj4dysYn==",
        "file3": "Jusj6Hism==",
        "file4": "Rhsy7Yhah=="
    }
}
', true);

/* Simulamos tu función agregando información de depuración */
function subirFichero($base64) {
    echo '<p>BASE64 recibido: ', $base64, '</p>', PHP_EOL;
}

/* Enumeramos los elementos e ignoramos el que se llame "nombre" */
foreach ($input['data'] as $clave => $base64) {
    if ($clave !== 'nombre') {
        subirFichero($base64);
    }
}
```

La salida obtenida es:

```
BASE64 recibido: Mhuc2dvCg==
BASE64 recibido: Yhj4dysYn==
BASE64 recibido: Jusj6Hism==
BASE64 recibido: Rhsy7Yhah==
```

### Optimizando el formato JSON

Lo normal es que el contenido del JSON facilite su análisis por la aplicación que recibe los datos, por lo tanto lo ideal es ajustar su contenido a una propiedad que enumere los archivos de manera inequívoca:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
        "nombre": "Nombre",
        "files": [
            "Mhuc2dvCg==",
            "Yhj4dysYn==",
            "Jusj6Hism==",
            "Rhsy7Yhah=="
        ]
    }
}
```

De modo que el código PHP se simplifica enormemente:

```
<?php
$input = json_decode('
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
        "nombre": "Nombre",
        "files": [
            "Mhuc2dvCg==",
            "Yhj4dysYn==",
            "Jusj6Hism==",
            "Rhsy7Yhah=="
        ]
    }
}
', true);

/* Simulamos tu función agregando información de depuración */
function subirFichero($base64) {
    echo '<p>BASE64 recibido: ', $base64, '</p>', PHP_EOL;
}

/* Enumeramos cada uno de los elementos */
foreach ($input['data']['files'] as $base64) {
    subirFichero($base64);
}
```

La salida obtenida es (igual que antes):

```
BASE64 recibido: Mhuc2dvCg==
BASE64 recibido: Yhj4dysYn==
BASE64 recibido: Jusj6Hism==
BASE64 recibido: Rhsy7Yhah==
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo usando un array y un foreach asi:

```
$files = array()
foreach($input['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'file') !== false) {
        $files[] = $value;
    }
}
```

O si quieres, puedes subir los archivos dentro del loop asi:

```
foreach($input['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'file') !== false) {
        subirFichero($value);
    }
}
```